# Adding data to many-to-many relation in Django database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-mysql

I am using django 2.2, python 3.6.8 on ubuntu 18.04 with mysql server.
I have courses, student and courses_student tables.
There is a many-to-many relation between courses and students.
In Courses model :

```
student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Öğrenci"))
```

I manually created a form in a template and making data insertions manually.
Views.py :

```
studentnamesuuidlist = request.POST.getlist('ogrenci_isimleri') #list

student1 = Student.objects.filter(uuid=studentnamesuuidlist[0])
coursesobject.student.set(student1)
student2 = Student.objects.filter(uuid=studentnamesuuidlist[1])
coursesobject.student.set(student2)
```

There are 2 students for this course. Student uuid's are coming from template form post.
When i run above lines, student2 record is created in courses_student joint table.
But student1 is not created. It should create both records but it is creating only one record in joint table.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.add` instead of `.set` see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).
`.set` rewrites and `.add` appends.

```py
studentnamesuuidlist = request.POST.getlist('ogrenci_isimleri') #list

student1 = Student.objects.filter(uuid=studentnamesuuidlist[0])
coursesobject.student.add(student1)
student2 = Student.objects.filter(uuid=studentnamesuuidlist[1])
coursesobject.student.add(student2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
    studentnamesuuidlist = request.POST.getlist('ogrenci_isimleri') #list

    student1 = Student.objects.get(uuid=studentnamesuuidlist[0])
    student2 = Student.objects.get(uuid=studentnamesuuidlist[1])
    coursesobject.student.add(student1,student2) 
    coursesobject.save()
```